# Why is there no overloaded valueOf method for floats in BigDecimal?

Tags: java

If I calculate all Values from 0.01 divided by 10 all is fine with doubles.

```
Stream.iterate(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.01), a -> a.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0))).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But if I use floats, it will break. The internal float representation of the values is not preferred for this task, but why is there no overloaded function in BigDecimal?

```
Stream.iterate(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.01f), a -> a.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0f))).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Because it was implemented that way?  In all seriousness...a float is smaller than a double in terms of precision and size, and personally I wouldn't see much value in using floats here.

Comment: I wouldn't use the valueOf method with doubles at all. One intension of BigDecimal is to ensure precision that cannot be guaranteed by doubles nor floats. I would use new BigDecimal("0.01") instead

Comment: Why use BigDecimal here? With a double constructor you could get 0.009999 or such. No precision. `BigDecimal.valueOf("0.01")` would do. And then the question float vs. double is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I ignored the String parameter. Wow. -.-

Comment: Only "breakage" I see here is that the output starts at `0.009999999776482582` and goes to `9.999999776482582E-12` ... which is simply conversion accuracy issue going from `float` to `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code will NOT break if you use floats. A double argument can accept float values, so there is no need for overloaded valueOf with a float argument.